# usage of react state a key to render a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

I'm trying to make a simple tic tac toe game in react:

```
 28 import './App.css';
 27 import { useState } from "react"
 26 
 25 const X = 1;
 24 const O = -1;
 23 const EMPTY = 0;
 22 
 21 const SYMBOLS = {X: "X", O: "O", EMPTY: "E"};
 20 
 19 var Square = ({idx, click}) => 
 18 {
 17     let [val, setVal] = useState(EMPTY);
 16 
 15     return (
 14         <button onClick={() => {click(setVal, idx);}}>{SYMBOLS[val]}</button>
 13     )
 12 }
 11 
 10 var App = () =>
  9 {
  8     let [turn, setTurn] = useState(X);
  7     let [state, setState] = useState(new Array(9).fill(EMPTY));
  6     let squares = new Array(9);
  5 
  4     let click = (setValFunc, idx) => 
  3     {
  2         setTurn(-turn);
  1         setValFunc(turn);
29          setState((prev) => (prev.map((s, i) => i === idx ? turn : s ))) 
  1     }
  2 
  3     for (let i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
  4     {   
  5         squares[i] = (<Square click={click} idx={i}/>);
  6     }
  7 
  8     return (
  9         <div>
 10             {squares}
 11         </div>
 12     )
 13 }
 14 
 15 export default App;
```

as you can see, I have three states: `X`, `O`, `EMPTY` for the board, represented by 1, -1, and 0 respectively.

but when I'm trying to access the `SYMBOLS` object to map number to symbol (when returning value from `Square`), the button is just empty.

what's wrong here?

Comment: `O: "O"` is a capital "o", not a zero. And `EMPTY` is a zero. Get in the habit of debugging your code with `console.log`, logging `SYMBOLS[val]` would have pointed you to to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andy Ray mentioned, the issue comes from the fact that you are using SYMBOLS[0], SYMBOLS[-1] and SYMBOLS[1] while your SYMBOLS object keys are X, O and EMPTY.

The solution is to redefine SYMBOLS:

```
const SYMBOLS = {
  [X]: 'X', // note the [X] notation that tells that the key should be the value of the variable X that's to say 1. 
  [O]: 'O',
  [EMPTY]: 'E'
}
```

Comment: damn I cant believe this went over my head.

Comment: I guess I'm used to the keys being actual strings from other languages

Comment: Values are converted to strings when used as Javascript object keys. That still won't make the string `0` (zero) equal the string `O` (capital "o"). This question should be closed as typo as the answer won't help others, and the title is not related to the issue.

Comment: numbers are converted to strings when accessing an object value. So it would actually solve the problem ;) `var test={'0':'testValue'};console.log(test[0]);`

Comment: @Andy Ray Also I think there is a misunderstanding on the issue/solution. The pb is that SYMBOLS was a map with keys 'O', 'X', 'EMPTY' while accessed with 1, -1 and 0 (EMPTY variable). My solution is to update the SYMBOLS dictionary to match how it's used (using '1','-1', '0' as keys). Using the [X],[O],[EMPTY] is just a way to keep data consistent and more readable than hardcoding '1','-1','0' keys

Comment: I understand that.